# SQL Server 2005 RANK function

Tags: sql-server-2005, function, rank

I have a problem in SQL Server 2005:

Suppose I have the table `PLAYER` (`string player, int score, bool Active`) and the this query :

```
SELECT PLAYER.player AS NAME,
   PLAYER.score AS SCORE,
   POSITION = CASE WHEN PLAYER.Active THEN RANK()OVER(ORDER BY score desc) else NULL end
from PLAYER
```

The problem is that when the player is not active, the positions generated are not consecutive.

For example :

```
JOHN,10000,1
PETER,5000,NULL (NOT ACTIVE)
CHARLES,2500,3 (SHOULD HAVE POSITION 2, NOT 3)
```

Sorry for my terrible English, I hope I have explained my point

Comment: What happens to the rank of the inactive players?? do you want to rank them or do you want to rank only the active players?

Comment: i want to rank only active players. not active must have null value un position column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @Player table
(
  player varchar(20),
  score int,
  state int
)

insert into @Player values ('JOHN', 10000, 1)
insert into @Player values ('PETER', 5000, NULL)
insert into @Player values ('PAUL', 5000, 2)
insert into @Player values ('CHARLES', 2500, 1)

select player as Name,
       score,
       case
          when state = 1 then
            rank() over(partition by state order by score desc)
          else null
       end as position
from @Player
```

Result:

```
Name                 score       position
-------------------- ----------- --------------------
PETER                5000        NULL
JOHN                 10000       1
CHARLES              2500        2
PAUL                 5000        NULL
```

Comment: Works as long as the bit type will not be converted to an int(since it already has values > 1).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Why/when would it be converted to an int?

Comment: I thought that active is a status since OP used values of 1, NULL and 3. That smells like it actually is a `int` (or will be). If it would be changed to an `int` datatype, the rank would be wrong since OP wants to order by score not active (active first by score, then the inactive).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - The `3` is the result from the query, not Active. Active is bool as per the first row.

Comment: that worked good for me, but the problem is that actually my "Active" column is not boolean, the real column is an integer called "state" and it must equal 1 to be active. How should the code be in that case?

Comment: @martin.softpro Then you should update your question with that information and please add some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
POSITION = 
   RANK()OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN Active IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC, score DESC)
```

**Edit**:

> ...but the problem is that actually my "Active" column is not boolean,
>   the real column is an integer called "state" and it must equal 1 to be
>   active. How should the code be in that case?

Then this should work:

```
POSITION = 
   RANK()OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN State = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, score DESC)
```

Comment: that didn't work,i got the highest position for the non active column

Comment: @martin.softpro: I cannot reproduce this, this orders by active highest score, then inactive highest score. Of course this does not return `null` for inactive. Anyway, i see that you got it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT PLAYER.player AS NAME, 
PLAYER.score AS SCORE, 
POSITION = RANK()OVER(ORDER BY score desc) 
from PLAYER
WHERE ACTIVE IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT PLAYER.player AS NAME, 
PLAYER.score AS SCORE,NULL  
from PLAYER
WHERE ACTIVE IS NULL
```

I am not sure how efficient this will be when compared to the already answered query but it is a little easier to understand.